# Ubuntu Server as Router, Static ip for macadr's

Tags: server, dhcp, router, static-ip

I have Ubuntu Server as Router. On it i have turned on DHCP Server, but i want to give static adresses to some devices (mac adresses) in my network, where I have to start? I tried to google it, and i was found nothing :(

Comment: Did you follow a how-to or a tutorial? If so which one?

Answer (score 1):

**Giving a pc/server present in the lan a static ip address**

This is necessary if you want to run a server on a pc inside the lan and need a port forwarded, for example a web server or bittorrent client.

This is quite a bit more complicated than for services running on the router itself, but still not too much of a challenge. First you have to set up the pc in the lan that runs the server (referred to from here on as the "host") with a static ip address. Because the ip addresses are allocated with DHCP, a host might be given a different ip address each time it connects to the network. You can easily give it a static ip address by telling the DHCP server to give it the same ip address each time.

Go into webmin and click the "Servers" section and select the DHCP server. In the hosts section click "Add a new host". Fill the details as shown:

"Host description" - Whatever you want, this is just to help you remember which host it is
"Host name" - Set this to the hostname of the host. This can be found by executing hostname on the host pc.
"Hardware Address" - This is the mac address of the host. This can be found be executing ifconfig on the host machine and looking at the mac address of the appropriate network card.
"Fixed IP address" - This is the ip address you want to give the host. This ip address should be in your local lan and should not be included in the group of ip addresses you already told the dhcp server to hand out dynamically. If you have been following this guide, it should be 192.168.0.X where X is a number from 2 to 99 inclusive.
"Host assigned to" - You can set this option to a subnet in order to use ip addresses within the dhcp dynamic allocation pool.

Copied from [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=926001) help page.

Comment: i forgot to tell that i don't have any GUI

Comment: Good answer. But this assumes that webmin is installed?